# How to create a custom-element with a property that can be use to style it

Tags: polymer

I’m new to polymer and I need your assistance. I will like to create a simple element like this: `<my-custom-element></my-custom-element>` and I will prefer if one can change the background colour of the element like this: `<my-custom-element backgroudcolor="#000"></my-custom-element>`.

I tried something like this:

```
<dom-module id=“my-custom-element”>
    <template>
       <style>div{height:70px; width:60px;}</style>
       <div></div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
          is: “my-custom-element”,
          properties: {
            backgroundcolor : {`
              type: String,
              value: #fff,
              notify: true
             }
          },
          created: function(){
            this.style.background = this.backgroundcolor;
          }
       })
  </script>`
</dom-module>
```

but that didn't workout. Please how can I go about achieving this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to let it know what 'this' is, I'm guessing it's the div, but you can do it by class or ID too (this way will only do it to the first thing it comes across that matches the criteria

```
Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("div").style.background = this.backgroundcolor
```

EDIT:

And some best practices would have you code look like this:

```
<dom-module id=“my-custom-element”>
   <style>
     #someid {
       height:70px; 
       width:60px;
     }
   </style>
   <template>
       <div id="someid"></div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
          is: “my-custom-element”,
          properties: {
            backgroundcolor : {
              type: String,
              value: #fff,
              notify: true
             }
          },

          ready: function()
          {
            Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#someid").style.background = this.backgroundcolor;
          }
       })
  </script>`
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Thank you, it work! A little tiny change is necessary though,  the `created` must be change to `ready` callback

Comment: @osa It would actually be better if you attach that code to an observer to the `backgroundcolor` property so that it will change it's background color every time it changes.